# Using method of characteristics to solve pde $xyu_x+u_y+u=4$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Using method of characteristics to solve pde $xyu_x+u_y+u=4$

My attempt:

$\frac{dx}{xy}=\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{u-4}$

Now take $\frac{dx}{xy}=\frac{dy}{1}\implies  \frac{dx}{x}=ydy \implies c_1=\frac{^{e^{\frac{y^2}{2}}}}{x}$

now $\frac{dy}{1}=\frac{du}{u-4}\implies y=\log|u-4|+\log c_2 \implies c_2= e^y(u-4)$

From both i am unable to find  $u$

thanks your time..

Comment: What are the initial conditions?

Comment: @Stuck..no initial conditions

Comment: Oh.. it seems to me you can just solve for $u$ via $c_2=e^y(u-4),$ no?

Comment: @Stuck.. I think we to find $u$ from $c_1,c_2$

Comment: You made some mistakes. It should be $$\frac{dx}{xy} = \frac{dy}{1} = \frac{du}{\color{green}{4 - u}}$$ and also $$\frac{dx}{x} = y dy \implies \ln x = \frac{y^{2}}{2} + C_{1} \implies x e^{\color{red}{-} y^{2}/2} = C_{1}$$ The other characteristic is $C_{2} = e^{y}(4 - u)$. The general solution is then $$C_{2} = f(C_{1}) \implies e^{y}(4 - u) = f(x e^{- y^{2}/2}) \implies u = 4 - e^{- y} f(x e^{- y^{2}/2})$$ for some differentiable function $f$.

Comment: @mattos Why is the solution given by $C_2=f(C_1)$?

Comment: @Stuck..Its called implict equation